# Is there any possibility to get subcolors from a color?

Tags: java, android, colors

I'm trying to create labels like this one:

[image: image of labels]

The thing is that I have to create this from a topic and subtopic, they come from server, and they are dynamic, I mean I don't know how many are, is up to admin, he can create as many as he wants.

So the idea is like I have a topic Maths and subtopics addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, etc..

I was thinking about create a color for Maths and then from that color get a similar color of it, like this :

[image: image2]

But programmatically, is that even possible? Or maybe you know any other way I also thought about creating like a default array with let's say 10 topics and 10 subtopic on each topic, and then assign it a color, it's a manual task, but as I said... it won't work if admin put 11 topics.

Comment: This seems more like a design question than a programming question.

Comment: No because I need to know if there's a way to get similar colors from one specific

Comment: And the question of "what colors match each other" isn't a programming question.